# Wordpress wiget admin panel

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to achive this thing in wordpress wiget admin panel : http://jsfiddle.net/George02/mkuxcwf5/1/

The problem is that the jQuery seems to not work .

```
public function form( $instance ) { ?>
<?php
wp_register_script('customscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/widgets/custom_widget/widget.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('customscript');
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="category-list">

    </ul>
    <div id="add-category">
        <select id="categories">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div id="btn-add">Add category</div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php }
```

widget.js contains the code from the fiddle. If I `View Source` of the page It's seems that the script is there, in the head section, and if I open up the console I can see the log from document ready function . I think the problem is that wordpress doesn't allow me to add items into DOM, because when I inspect the $list element I can see that he has a `<li>` inside it.I'm right or it's something else?

Comment: If you have more than 1 of those widgets you'll have multiple clashing IDs, also can we see your widget.js in full?

Comment: After changing all `<div id="">` with `<div class="">` seems that the script is working, but has a inexplicable problem. When I do `$('.category-list').append(newCategoryHTML);` a new jQuery object is created, so when I log $('.category-list') I can see in the console 2 `<ul>` tags. What about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what's happen :

When you create a widget and init it in functions.php he will be placed, with all it's content(that means the html from `public function form( $instance )`), into `<div id="widget-list">` (the area from the left of the admin panel which list all the widgets). So when you will drag it onto the widget area you will have 2 of them on the admin panel. One placed into `<div id="widget-list">` and one into `<div id="widget-area">`. So your jQuery script need to work only with the widget from the widget area, for that you will need to have something like $("#widget-area .another-selector") in your script .

Another thing that it can be easily understand from what I wrote above is that all your divs (elements) must have `class`es and not `id`s.